# How to declare a dynamic object's property type?

Tags: c#, object, dynamic

I have the following issue :

I am using dynamic object ( ExpandoObject ) , whose properties I want to change runtime.
What is the clue ... I want my properties to be doubles , because the user control , which I am using can not identify that the property is double if it's type is not double. As I know there is known type of the properties of the dynamic objects which should be double in the case , but it does not works for this control. So is there any explicit way , when I declare new property of the dynamic object to tell that it is double ?

Thanks in advance,
Yoan

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `ExpandoObject`, just *assign a double*:

```
    dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
    obj.Foo = 123.45;
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Foo.GetType()); // System.Double
```

However, I would say that a `dynamic` object is probably not a good choice for UI binding (to a user-control), since they don't have a strong property model. In fact, most UI bindings aren't even up-to-date with `dynamic`, and will be trying to use `System.ComponentModel` (which doesn't know about `dynamic`).

Comment: I tried to assign double to it , of course , but it does not read it as a double but as object I suppose , because it does not recognizes the value.

Comment: @YoanPetrov what exactly is the user control, and how are you telling it about the object?

Comment: I am binding to the object , and it displays all its properties. When i double-click some of the properties , it should display the value and do calculations with it , but actualy it doesn't get it as a double but as object and doesn't make any cast ...

Comment: @Yoan well, in many ways that is accurate. When using the dynamic API, everything **is** `object`... maybe `dynamic` / `ExpandoObject` simply isn't the way to do this. You didn't answer: what is the UI control you are using here? Ultimately, support for this is down the the control.